# Any ways to Simplify Daboussi's Argument for Prime Number Theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

One [strategy](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean-paul.allouche/20060929144515189.pdf) to prove the Prime number theorem involves removing some factors:

$$ \limsup_{x \to \infty} \underbrace{\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(x)}_{\color{red}{A}}\leq 
\prod_{p \leq y} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)
\int_1^\infty \underbrace{ \frac{1}{t}\sum_{n \leq t} \mu(n)\mathbf{1}_y(n)}_{\color{blue}{B}} \times \frac{dt}{t} $$

The averages $A$ and $B$ are related since we are adding up the Möbius function on the subset of the integers whose factors $p \leq y$.

Here $\mathbf{1}_y(n) = 1$ if all the prime factors $p | n$ are less than $y$ and $0$ otherwise.  Can't think of a better way of explaining this at the moment, it is called $v_y(n)$ in Daboussi's paper.

Proving that $\int_1^\infty \dots \ll \log y$ is rather convoluted.  Are there any simpler ways to establish Daboussi's intermediate result?

Comment: I don't know. Have you seen the exposition of Daboussi's proof in Tenenbaum and Mendes France, The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution, published by the AMS as Volume 6 of the Student Mathematical Library?

Comment: I think that while it is true that Daboussi’s proof is a nice application of what someone called ‘phipsiology’ (counting numbers without small/large prime factors), there is no way around the observation that Selberg’s elementary proof is simpler and easier to understand.